# Prove that if $A$ is a square matrix such that all of the rows of $A$ have the same sum $k$ then $k$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Prove that if $A$ is a square matrix such that all of the rows of $A$ have the same sum $k$
(i.e. the sum of the entries in each row is $k$) then $k$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

my effort

I think that being an eigenvalue of $A$ implies that $kv=Av$ for some vector $v \neq 0$. Furthermore, I know that $[a_i]=k$ if we let $a_i$ denote the $i$-th row of $A$. However, I do not seem to be able to find a link between these two facts. Could anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 4):

Hint: What happens when you right multiply matrix $A$ by column vector $v$ (i.e. perform $Av$) when all entries of $v$ are equal to $1$?

Comment: That every element in Av is equal to k I think? So that would indeed mean that k is an eigenvalue in this

Comment: We will get  a vector with entries $a+b=k$ and $b+c=k$ so it is $k .v.$

Comment: @AdelHassan Yes that is correct.

Comment: @AdelHassan A subtle point here is that the *left* eigenvalues of $A$ (i.e. those values of $\lambda$ such that $u^\ast A = \lambda u^\ast$ for some vector $u$) coincide with the *right* eigenvalues (i.e. those values of $\lambda$ such that $Av=\lambda v$ for some vector $v$).